# What's the name of the manufacturer of my really cheap Chinese tablet?

Tags: updates

I recently got into high school. I've received a really cheap Chinese tablet as a gift. I can conclude this because it's Box just says "Android Tablet PC". No model name, No manufacturer name, NO NOTHING...!! 
As the latest need of new generation and 21'st century, it is really dumb, 'cause it stuck with stock Android 4.1.1 ... It won't even upgrade to Android Jelly Bean(4.2.2).
As the new Android Kitkat (4.4.4) is in the market, I really want to upgrade to that android.

It specs(Personally-made)..

Supports Wi-Fi, GPS, but no Bluetooth.

Has 1 GB internal storage, NAND Flash of 5.32 GB and it even supports a SD card.

It's RAM is 1 GB

It's Model Number is **AM818RC**

It's Kernal Version is **3.0.8+**

It's Build Number is **rk30sdk-eng4.1.1 JRO03H 20121228.140006 release-keys**...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible to guess the "name of the manufacturer", as they have not even provided that information on tablet itself.

If you want to use Android Kitkat on the tablet, you can **TRY** some custom ROMs such as [CyanogenMod](http://download.cyanogenmod.org/), with any available binary image for a tablet with almost all specifications same as your's, including processor, RAM, NAND etc.

And **I'm not sure whether this will work or not.** So make sure to have a complete backup.

Comment: I have an extra 8 GB SD card on which i can backup...By the way.. HOW TO DO BACKUP YOUR APPS + APPS CACHE (e.g = Your record of subway surfers....Your points in HILL CLIMB RACING...etc.)


could you also tell me how to download and use CYANOGENMOD.
I could also give you my email to send me a detailed process of downloading and using it to upgrade to android 4.4..Regards

Comment: CyanogenMod is a custom ROM.  You have to find the right version yourself: http://download.cyanogenmod.org/    And use Titanium Backup or MyBackup Root to backup data.  You have to be rooted.

Answer (score 0):

According to a quick [Google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=android%20tablet%20AM818RC) based on the model number you provided, this might be [Oracom Korea's](https://www.facebook.com/Oracomkorea) [AM 818 8" tablet](https://www.facebook.com/Oracomkorea).

Answer (score -1):

As KeshavaGN has said CyanogenMod is a safe option(**provided you have read the risks associated with it**) to root your phone to Android 4.4.4(Kit-Kat) but a small note of precaution is that the kit-Kat OS occupies a min of 3 GB space so later you will not have enough storage on board.

(As given by your specs you  will have only 2 GB free of storage space for your own use to download other apps)

Comment: great then why didn't you include it in your question that you can expand up to 16 GB.

Comment: I wrote "it even supports a SD card"

Comment: Dear Atta "it even supports a SD card" doesn't specify how much GB space your device can support.If you end up having an SD Card more then its limitations then the device starts to lag a lot.So for best answers plz write the complete details of hardware/software.

Comment: Thanks 4 d Tip....  
I have an extra 8 GB SD card on which i can backup...By the way.. HOW TO DO BACKUP YOUR APPS + APPS CACHE (e.g = Your record of subway surfers....Your points in HILL CLIMB RACING...etc.) could you also tell me how to download and use CYANOGENMOD. I could also give you my email to send me a detailed process of downloading and using it to upgrade to android 4.4..Regards

Comment: ANd 1 thing more... it has smthing "rock chip'in it.. i dunt know whether its a processor or a rom...